# Maximum Likelihood without density?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, soft-question, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

The maximum likelihood-estimator of a parameter $\theta$ is defined as the maximizer $\hat \theta$ of the joint density $f$ of the data $x_1,\ldots,x_n$:
$$
f(x_1,\ldots,x_n; \theta).
$$

The assumption, in my understanding, is that the data actually follows the distribution belonging to that density.

Question: Is there a canonical extension of maximum likelihood to the case where the distribution of the data cannot be assumed to have a density (w.r.t. Lebesgue-measure)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only concerned with families of distributions having no density with respect to Lebesgue measure, but possibly having densities with respect to other measures, then this is done all the time with discrete distributions. Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\operatorname{i.i.d. Poisson}(\lambda).$ Then the density with respect to counting measure on $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}^n$ is
$$
(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\lambda^{x_i} e^{-\lambda}}{x_i!} = \frac{\lambda^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} e^{-n\lambda}}{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i!} \text{ for } x = 0,1,2,3,\ldots
$$
and the likelihood function is
$$
\lambda \mapsto \frac{\lambda^{x_i} e^{-\lambda}}{x_i!} = \frac{\lambda^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} e^{-n\lambda}}{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i!}.
$$
Certainly these measures are not absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.

More generally, suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\operatorname{i.i.d.}$ and for every set $A$ in some sigma-algebra and every value of $\theta$ in the parameter space, the probability ${\Pr}_\theta(X_i\in A)$ is well defined.

If for every measurable set $A$ we have $\displaystyle\sum_\theta {\Pr}_\theta(X_i\in A) <\infty,$ then the set-function $\displaystyle A\mapsto \sum_\theta {\Pr}_\theta (X_i\in A),$ although not a probability measure, is a measure with respect to which every one of the probability measures ${\Pr}_\theta$ has a density function. In some cases any one of the probability measures in the parametrized family is a measure with respect to which all of the others are absolutely continuous. And I suspect in some cases a sum of two of them might be enough.

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but could you please explain how to construct the density of ${\Pr}_\theta$ w.r.t. $A \mapsto \sum_\theta {\Pr}_\theta (X_i\in A)$?

For any $\theta_0 \in \Theta$ we want $ f_{\theta_0} \ge 0$ s.t. for any event $A$, 
$$
P_{\theta_0}(X_i \in A) = \int_A f_{\theta_0} d \left(\sum_\theta ({\Pr}_\theta \circ X_i^{-1})\right) =\\ \sum_\theta \int_A f_{\theta_0} d({\Pr}_\theta \circ X_i^{-1}) = \sum_\theta \int_A f_{\theta_0}\circ X_i d{\Pr}_\theta.
$$

But then I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: Let's try a concrete example: Say you have $Y = \left. \begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability } 1/2, \\ 0 & \text{with probability } 1/2, \end{cases} \right\}$ and the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $Y=0$ is given by $X = \left. \begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability } 1/2, \\ 0 & \text{with probability } 1/2, \end{cases} \right\}$ and the the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=1$ is $e^{-x}\,dx \text{ for } x\ge0.$ Then in order to find a marginal (i.e. unconditional) probability density function for $X,$ we first add together those$\,\ldots\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$two conditional distributions of $X,$ and get this measure $m:$ $$ 
m(A) = \int_A 1e^{-x} \,dx + \big(1 \text{ if } 0\in A\big) + \big(1\text{ if }1\in A\big). $$ Then the density is $$ f(x) = \left. \begin{cases} 1/4 & \text{if } x=0 \text{ or } x=1, \\  1 & \text{if } x\ge0\ \&\ 0\ne x\ne 1, \\ 0 &\text{if } x<0. \end{cases} \right\} $$ Then you have $$ \Pr( X\in A) = \int_A f(x)\, dm(x). $$